# Ubuntu 11.10 completely freezes

Tags: 11.10, freeze

Hello all. My Ubuntu 11.10 installation seems to suddenly lock up. I cannot move my mouse or use the keyboard, all screen activity stops, and I have to do a hard reboot. Is there an y method to repair this? It started a few days ago.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @JorgeCastro In my opinion, this is not a bug, but a valid question(I assume you thought of a memory leak), but this is a user trying to get help with freezing(containing instructions that other users may use to diagnose constant hangs) and possibly adding badram addresses to the grub config to avoid bad areas.

Answer (score 1):

Before you panic, try the magic SysRq trick. Find the key on your keyboard labelled <kbd>PRT SCRN|SYSRQ</kbd>(Could be arranged differently). Hold that key, <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd>. This invokes the Linux oom_kill which could aid in recovering. Also, try this with <kbd>B</kbd> instead of <kbd>M</kbd> and see it it reboots then. If it does, then you are either out of memory(If you have a swap partition, your disk may be active), or you have another software issue. If not, it is hardware. Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> during the freeze. Does that work? If so, you can use `top` after logging in to ascertain the process causing the issue.

Try running `vmstat 1` in the Teminal. In a comment, tell us your swapin and swapout values.

Also ,try running `top`, giving us the top `%CPU` values, then pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. and the RSS and SHR values of the top processes. This can help pinpoint the cause. Also, are you using Skype, by any chance? There is a reported memory leak in it.

Comment: I followed your first instruction and the only thing my OS did was it captured the screen couple of times

Comment: swapin 0 swapout 1484, that's the min and max values.


top - 23:02:36 up 10 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.64, 1.76, 1.20
Tasks: 155 total,   3 running, 152 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.0%us,  2.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.9%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    993648k total,   895432k used,    98216k free,    89128k buffers
Swap:  1013756k total,    11072k used,  1002684k free,   190168k cached

Comment: I have skype installed but not using it

Comment: did I provide you with all information you need?

Comment: Were you holding ALT when tried to use the key combo? Or do you have a separate SysRQ key? Also, is the info about memory from after the lockup or before(using the terminal given with ctrl +alt+F1)? Were you able to switch to a terminal using that key combo?

Comment: Is Skype set to auto-start and auto-login? This could be very important.

Comment: yes, I was holding all that keys you mentioned. When I pressed ctrl+alt+f1 I was taken to root but I didn't know how to switch back to desktop so I rebooted PC. skype is not set on auto-start.

Comment: it happend again today, but I couldn't do anything, couldn't even turn off the num lock light on keyboard

Comment: What kind of CPU do you use? Can you do a memtest from the correct choice in Grub(Main pre-boot menu)

Comment: CPU is Pentium 4 2.8 GHz. I will report you as soon as I make memtest

Comment: memtest reported some errors, maybe that' why it's freezing

Comment: You'll need to tell me where the error is and I will show you how to add badram info to Grub.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3750/discussion-between-obsessivefoss-and-alen)